# JMX role-based access control with custom authorization

Tags: java, oracle, jmx, access-control, role-based-access-control

I am new to JMX and am trying out JMX for remote monitoring and followed the oracle documentation on [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) and am trying out the samples from the post [Authentication and Authorization in JMX RMI connectors](https://blogs.oracle.com/lmalventosa/entry/jmx_authentication_authorization). I could create the Hello World MBean example with password and access files and now I want to implement the same with a custom Forwarder for authorization (use case 2 in [2](https://blogs.oracle.com/lmalventosa/entry/jmx_authentication_authorization)).

I wrote the java code as shown but when I log into jConsole with 
**monitorRole** (readOnly)
 credentials it gives a connection failed error but works perfect for the **controlRole** (readWrite).

Following is the piece code for authorization from custom forwarder. Please let me know what changes needs to be done in the code for monitorRole authorization.

```
// "role1" can perform any operation other than "createMBean" and "unregisterMBean"
            if (identity.equals("controlRole")) {
                return method.invoke(mbs, args);
            }

// "role2" can only call "getAttribute" on the MBeanServerDelegate MBean
            if (identity.equals("monitorRole") &&
                    methodName.equals("getAttribute") &&
                    MBeanServerDelegate.DELEGATE_NAME.equals(args[0])) {
                return method.invoke(mbs, args);
            }
```

The complete code is is as follows:

```
public class Agent {

public static class MBSFInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    public static MBeanServerForwarder newProxyInstance() {

        final InvocationHandler handler = new MBSFInvocationHandler();

        final Class[] interfaces =
                new Class[] {MBeanServerForwarder.class};

        Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                MBeanServerForwarder.class.getClassLoader(),
                interfaces,
                handler);

        return MBeanServerForwarder.class.cast(proxy);
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {

        final String methodName = method.getName();

        if (methodName.equals("getMBeanServer")) {
            return mbs;
        }

        if (methodName.equals("setMBeanServer")) {
            if (args[0] == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null MBeanServer");
            if (mbs != null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("MBeanServer object " +
                        "already initialized");
            mbs = (MBeanServer) args[0];
            return null;
        }

        // Retrieve Subject from current AccessControlContext
        AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();
        Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(acc);

        // Allow operations performed locally on behalf of the connector server itself
        if (subject == null) {
            return method.invoke(mbs, args);
        }

        // Restrict access to "createMBean" and "unregisterMBean" to any user
        if (methodName.equals("createMBean") || methodName.equals("unregisterMBean")) {
            throw new SecurityException("Access denied");
        }

        // Retrieve JMXPrincipal from Subject
        Set<JMXPrincipal> principals = subject.getPrincipals(JMXPrincipal.class);
        if (principals == null || principals.isEmpty()) {
            throw new SecurityException("Access denied");
        }
        Principal principal = principals.iterator().next();
        String identity = principal.getName();

        // "role1" can perform any operation other than "createMBean" and "unregisterMBean"
        if (identity.equals("controlRole")) {
            return method.invoke(mbs, args);
        }

        // "role2" can only call "getAttribute" on the MBeanServerDelegate MBean
        if (identity.equals("monitorRole") &&
                methodName.equals("getAttribute") &&
                MBeanServerDelegate.DELEGATE_NAME.equals(args[0])) {
            return method.invoke(mbs, args);
        }

        throw new SecurityException("Access denied");
    }

    private MBeanServer mbs;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Ensure cryptographically strong random number generator used
    // to choose the object number - see java.rmi.server.ObjID
    //
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.randomIDs", "true");

    // Start an RMI registry on port 3000.
    //
    System.out.println("Create RMI registry on port 3000");
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(3000);

    // Retrieve the PlatformMBeanServer.
    //
    System.out.println("Get the platform's MBean server");
    MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

//   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Construct the ObjectName for the Hello MBean we will register
    ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("com.example:type=Hello");

    // Create the Hello World MBean
    Hello mbean = new Hello();

    // Register the Hello World MBean
    mbs.registerMBean(mbean, mbeanName);


 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// Environment map.

    System.out.println("Initialize the environment map");
    HashMap<String,Object> env = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    // Provide SSL-based RMI socket factories.
    //
    // The protocol and cipher suites to be enabled will be the ones
    // defined by the default JSSE implementation and only server
    // authentication will be required.
    //
    SslRMIClientSocketFactory csf = new SslRMIClientSocketFactory();
    SslRMIServerSocketFactory ssf = new SslRMIServerSocketFactory();
    env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_CLIENT_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, csf);
    env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_SERVER_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, ssf);

    // Provide the password file used by the connector server to
    // perform user authentication. The password file is a properties
    // based text file specifying username/password pairs.
    //
//        env.put(JMXConnectorServer.AUTHENTICATOR, new RealmJMXAuthenticator());

    // Provide the access level file used by the connector server to
    // perform user authorization. The access level file is a properties
    // based text file specifying username/access level pairs where
    // access level is either "readonly" or "readwrite" access to the
    // MBeanServer operations.
    //
    env.put("jmx.remote.x.password.file", "jmxremote.password");

    // Create an RMI connector server.
    //
    // As specified in the JMXServiceURL the RMIServer stub will be
    // registered in the RMI registry running in the local host on
    // port 3000 with the name "jmxrmi". This is the same name the
    // out-of-the-box management agent uses to register the RMIServer
    // stub too.
    //
    System.out.println("Create an RMI connector server");
    JMXServiceURL url =
            new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:3000/jmxrmi");
    JMXConnectorServer cs =
            JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, env, mbs);

    MBeanServerForwarder mbsf = MBSFInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance();
    cs.setMBeanServerForwarder(mbsf);

    // Start the RMI connector server.
    //
    System.out.println("Start the RMI connector server");
    cs.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you paste the "Connection refused" stack trace?

Comment: Can I know where I can find the stack trace? It doesn't log in the terminal and the command I use to run jconsole is: jconsole -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=admin123. I only get the connection refused error in a message box in jConsole.

Comment: That link has been removed from the Oracle website :(

Comment: Run jconsole with the `-debug` option. Did you resolve this successfully?